# Killed by something that leaves a crater?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I'm playing No Man's Sky on PC. I was at my base trying to interact with a portable refiner I left next to a building when suddenly there was a crash and I died.

When I respawned, there was no "Killed by XYZ" message, and the spot of my death (about 500 yards away) has an impact crater.

My planet is peaceful except for a few spider-looking little aliens. **The Sentinels are benign. What could have possibly killed me?** I saw and heard nothing when it happened -- no animal or angry sentinel noises, just a boom/crash. The 'shields are down' message flashed at the same time I died, so it was pretty much instantaneous.

My only idea was that maybe I was hit by a meteorite, but I've never seen meteorites so far in the game (and Googling doesn't seem to bring up anything for that.) The gamepedia page on [Death](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Death) doesn't list anything relevant either.

Here's what the impact crater looked like when I went back to get my stuff. Notice it's *under* the refiner.

[image: Scene of the Crime.]

Comment: It looks like the crater that is created by a grenade of some sort. Could it be possible you accidentally blew yourself up? I’ve done that once or twice before, when I didn’t realize I had my grenades activated.

Comment: I've only been playing for about 3 hours, I don't think I have any explosives. I usually kill things with my mining beam, and I just made the boltcaster but that was after my explosive death. I don't *think* I blew myself up; if I did, I'm not sure how.

Comment: No worries, just inquiring :) Best of luck in NMS!

Comment: I've seen graves occasionally create those little craters but not always. It seems to happen particularly when there are things in the same spot. The refinery being so close may have just created the little hole because I've died and had no crater. 
Best guess is something glitched out and you got jipped and it wasn't legit. I have no idea what external explosive force could have killed you

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas add to your description above what the state was of your multitool and other items equipped, this will give other people the ease to eliminate obvious things

Comment: I'm not sure by any measure, but the crater looks like the result of a physics error like the type one would get playing a game like space engineers- in that game occasionally objects attached to (specifically terrain) meshes can cause weird physics interactions that can kill PCs

Comment: I never played that game, but some potential ideas from other games: when the game gets laggy, when I experience (severe) frame drops, or even when the game is running too fast (too many FPS), or just completely randomly, my character gets crushed by the ground itself or stuffs nearby and dies. Don't know if getting crushed is a death reason in your game, but maybe your character got crushed by the refiner.

Comment: If playing on Steam, did you perchance opt in to the Beta release?

Answer (score 0):

If you had a grenade launcher or geology cannon equipped, you may have misclicked and blew yourself up.
killing you and leaving a crater that size.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments, at the time this happened I had only been playing for 3 hours and had no weapons in my multitool. At the time I had a terrain manipulator, plus the original upgrades, that's it.

Comment: Oh sorry, in that case I have no idea what happened.